# Saving projects to more than one file or path

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to have the output in Video Editing, go to more then one location at the same time?

Such as when rendering the project it would go not only to a desktop file and but also a file on a external hard drive at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any way to do that by default. That's why wrote a little add-on for you.

The add-on allows you to create a list of paths that the file should be saved to. Then every time a render is written to disk it is automatically copied to the specified paths.

The add-on can be downloaded here: https://github.com/oweissbarth/blender_multisave/releases/download/0.0.1/multisave_0_0_1.zip

To install the add-on click on "Edit" > "Preferences" > "Add-ons" > "Install..." and select the downloaded zip file and click "Install Add-on". Then activate the add-on by clicking on the checkbox next the its name.

[image: activate the addon]
The add-on will then appear in the properties editor in the output tab as its own panel called "MultiSave". You can add a new path to save to by clicking the "plus"-icon.  You can change the path of an item by double clicking it. And finally you can remove an item by selecting it from the list clicking the "x"-icon.

[image: addon-ui]

The source code is on github: https://github.com/oweissbarth/blender_multisave/

Comment: Thanks for the help with very clear instructions, but I have a problem the multisave does send a file to different locations but only one location is readable and that's the one initially set in the output folder. I've tried various combinations but get the same result. The files I'm sending are mp4 video. Maybe I'm not doing something right

Comment: Ok. I will do more testing and get back to you.

Comment: Ok. It was only working for image sequences but not for movies. I fixed that and made a new version. Please try again with the new version from here: https://github.com/oweissbarth/blender_multisave/releases/download/0.0.2/multisave_0_0_2.zip